# Permutations and Combinations - divisors of a number

Tags: permutations, prime-factorization

Question:
A number $n$ is given as $2^{31}3^{19}$. Find the number of divisors of $n^2$ which are less than $n$ and not a divisor of $n$.

Well the total number of divisors of a number is given by adding one to the power and multiplying them. Not sure how I would proceed for this question however. Any hint?

Comment: Well, if we drop the "less than $n$" part, you can simply substract the number of divisors of $n^2$ to the number of divisors of $n$ (which are really easy to compute with your formula), since any divisor of $n$ is also a divisor of $n^2$. However I don't know how to handle as quickly the "less than $n$" part.

Comment: @Traklon haha that came to my mind as well. However, the less than 'n' part makes it quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The exponent of 2 or 3 (or both) in the divisors of $n^2$ which do not divide $n$ must be greater than 31 and 19, respectively.

Comment: Ummm..... how to satisfy condition of 'less than n'?

Comment: Well, for all divisors $d$, $\dfrac{n}{d}$ is also a divisor and if one is less than $n$, the other is greater, so the number of divisors of $n^2$ that are less than $n$ is $\dfrac{\tau(n^2)-1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

you want the divisors $d$ of $2^{62}3^{38}$ that are smaller than $2^{31}3^{19}$ and satisfy one of those properties (at most can be met at a time)

$2^{32}$ divides $d$.

$3^{19}$ divides $d$.

For the first notice you want $2d$ to be a divisor of $2^{31}3^{19}$ that is smaller than $3^{19}$.  So classify according to the exponent of $3$ in the factorization of $d$.

Let $d=2^j3^k$. Then $2d=2^{j+1}3^k$. so you want $j+1\leq 31$ so that $2^{j+1}\leq3^{19-k}$. How many $j$ are there for a given $k$?. Take log on both sides and you want $(j+1)\log(2)\leq(19-k)\log3\iff j\leq \frac{\log(3)(19-k)}{\log(2)}-1$

You just have to be carefull this number does not exceed $31$, but it doesn't.

Thus what you want is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{18}\lfloor\frac{\log(3)(19-k)}{\log(2)}-1\rfloor$.

You have to do the same thing for the second case (but you have to be carefull because when $k$ is $0$ it is possible the bound will exceed $19$, so you need to do a little careful casework.

Comment: $\frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}\approx1.58496$ and $\frac{\log{2}}{\log{2}}\approx 0.7615$ for your calculation :)